# Custom methods for graphics in java.awt.graphics

Tags: java, swing, graphics, awt, java-2d

So right now, I'm new to using java awt graphics. I've gotten the basics down, like how to actually put things on the screen, but my main issue is that I'm trying to create custom methods for use outside of the class file.

For my screen class:

```
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.*;
    import javax.swing.*;
    public class Screen extends JPanel{
        Graphics g = null;
        public void createBox(int x, int y, int width, int height){
            g.fillRect(x, y, width, height);
        }
    }
```

For my Draw class, using the screen class as well:

```
    import javax.swing.*;
    public class Draw{
        public static void main(String[] args) {

            JFrame f = new JFrame("Shapes");
            f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            Screen s = new Screen();
            s.createBox(10,10,10,10);
            f.add(s);
            f.setSize(512, 512);
            f.setVisible(true);
        }

    }
```

Even when I have Graphics g; without it being declared, I still get the same error being:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at Screen.createBox(Screen:java:7)
at Draw.main(Draw:java:8)
```

createBox() is supposed to be used outside of the Screen class so I can still use fillRect() but with a different name (I hope this makes sense).

Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

> Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong?

Don't try to retain a reference to a `Graphics` object! Instead override the `paintComponent(Graphics)` method and use that (valid, not `null`) graphics instance. To trigger a paint, call `repaint()`.

All this stuff is covered in the [tutorial on custom painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/). Go through it!

Comment: The things is, I don't want to use paintComponent. I want to make it so if I typed in createBox in a different class, I could create a rectangle on the screen.

Comment: The thing is, I don't really care what you want. This is just the correct way to do custom painting. OTOH you might use a `BufferedImage` as a painting surface..

Comment: Then you didn't answer my question. I'm referring as of to what I did wrong not the correct way of painting. I was trying to put a box on the screen in a different way.

Comment: *"as of to what I did wrong not the correct way of painting."* Not doing custom painting the correct way ***is*** what you did wrong.